# A Question on Expectation of measurable and independent variable.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $X_t$ and $Y_t$ be stochastic processes on some range. Given that $X_t$ is independent to $F_t$ and $Y_t$ is $F_t$ measurable and suppose all terms in the expectation are defined, can I conclude that
$E[XY]= E[X_t]E[Y_t]$?  What I know is this holds given sigma algebras for $X_t$ and $Y_t$ generated by $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are independent.

Partial attempt:

$$E[XY]=E[E[X_t\cdot Y_t |F_t]]=E[ Y_t E[X_t |F_t]] = E[Y_t E[X_t]]=E[Y_T]E[X_t].$$
Does this holds true?

Any insight is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but I'm not sure what you mean by "this holds given sigma algebras for $X_t$ and $Y_t$ generated by $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are independent."

Comment: @user6247850 Thank you for your response.  It is very helpful...  All I know is Two random variables $X$and $Y$ are independent provided $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ are indepedent?  $\sigma(X)$ is the smallest sigma algebra that makes $X$ measurable.